# Python Regex to check for characters problem, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, regex, search, findall

Being new to Regex, I am working on a project that allows me to check if a password contains lowercase characters, uppercase and numerical ones. 
Here is the code:

```
text = "azeAZE123"
compilealpha = re.compile(r'[a-z]*')
compileAlpha = re.compile(r'[A-Z]*')
compilenum = re.compile(r'[0-9]*')
checkalpha = compilealpha.findall(text)
checkAlpha = compileAlpha.findall(text)
checknum = compilenum.findall(text)
print(checkAlpha)
print(checkalpha)
print(checknum)
```

What I do not understand is that I get an output like this one:

```
['', '', '', 'AZE', '', '', '', '']
['aze', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '123', '']
```

Could anyone explain to me what happened and what am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Try replacing the `*` by a `+` for having at least one character. The `*` stands for *0 or more of the preceding expression*. What is the desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expressions specify the quantity specifier `*`, *0* or more matches.  When combined with `findall()`, your regular expression matches empty substrings as well.

If you want to check if the regular expression has *one* or more matches, use `r'[A-Z]+'` instead.

Since you might be more interested in whether you have a match, and less interested in what that match is, you might consider using the regexp `search()` function instead of `findall()`, which will evaluate to a boolean.